# Heat equation with periodic initial conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}, f \in C(\mathbb{R})$ be $[0,1]^n-$periodic.

Consider then the problem:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}\partial_t u -\Delta_x u = 0\quad t>0\\u(x,0) = f(x)\quad t=0\end{matrix}\right.$$

Show that $$\lim_{t \to \infty}u(x,t) = \int_{[0,1]^n}f(y)dy$$

---

We can find a solution of the PDE by taking
$$u(x,t) = \int_\mathbb{R^n} \Phi(x-y,t) f(y)dy$$

with $\Phi(x-y,t) = \frac{e^{-\frac{|x-y|^2}{4t}}}{(4\pi t)^{\frac{n}{2}}}$ the heat kernel. I know that $\int_\mathbb{R^n} \Phi(x-y,t)dy=1$ for all $t>0$.

Consider the set of points in $\mathbb{z}^n$ and take the partition of $\mathbb{R}^n = \bigcup_{z \in \mathbb{Z}^n} \left([0,1]^n+z\right)$

We have then that
$$u(x,t) = \sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}^d}\int_{[0,1]^n+z}\Phi(x-y,t)f(y)dy = \sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}^d}\int_{[0,1]^n}\Phi(x-y+z,t)f(y+z)dy$$
$$=\sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}^d}\int_{[0,1]^n}\Phi(x-y+z,t)f(y)dy$$

Now I'd like to find some way to justify something like
$$\int_{[0,1]^n}\Phi(x-y+z,t)f(y)dy \to \left[\int_{[0,1]^n}f(y)dy\right]\left[\int_{[0,1]^n}\Phi(x-y+z,t)dy\right]\mbox{ as }t \to \infty$$

which would solve the question. How would I do that?

---

Attempt to show it:

$$\left|\int_{[0,1]^n}\Phi(x-y+z,t)f(y)dy - \left[\int_{[0,1]^n}f(w)dw\right]\left[\int_{[0,1]^n}\Phi(x-y+z,t)dy\right]\right| = $$
$$=\left|\int_{[0,1]^n}\Phi(x-y+z,t)\left[f(y) - \int_{[0,1]^n}f(w)dw\right]dy\right|$$
$$\leq \sup_{y \in [0,1]^n}\left[f(y) - \int_{[0,1]^n}f(w)dw\right] \int_{[0,1]^n}\Phi(x-y+z,t)dy$$

We can guarantee that $sup$ is finite because $f$ is periodic on $[0,1]^n$ and continuous, therefore bounded.

Now, as $t \to \infty$ we have that the function $\Phi(x-y+z,t)$ goes to $0$ by the definition. As the integral of $\Phi$ is $1$ for all $t>0$ we must have that, in the bounded square $[0,1]^n$ the integral must go to $0$.

and so we have proved the convergence we needed.

Is this correct? Thanks in advance.

---

Edit: $\color{red}{\mbox{My attempt is incorrect}}$. As I colleague pointed out to me, my argument would be valid for any value instead of $\int f(y)dy$. I only saw that every term in the summation goes to $0$, which isn't enough. I'd need some form of uniform convergence to pass the limit inside the summation in order to use any results concerning the limit of the terms on summation.

Our professor said to use the fact that periodic functions can be approximated uniformly by trigonometric polynomials, so we'd solve the problem for a trigonometric function and then by the uniform convergence we would have solved for any periodic function. Can anyone help on that? Thanks.

Comment: Magnificent question. May I ask your source for this question? I'd assume it is from some PDE book , but I'm not sure. Also, are you aware that periodic functions can be approximated uniformly by trigonometric polynomials (for example , Fejer's theorem) or would you need a reference for this? Your professor has made a very sensible remark : I'm quite surprised I haven't seen a similar argument before, though. I will try this question if you provide me with the reference.

Comment: Unfortunatey, don't have the time to try to write a full answer, but have you tried to apply to $u(t,x)$ the Laplace trasform respect to the time $t$ on $u(x,t)$ and see what happens to $\hat{u}(s,x)$ by applying the [final value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_value_theorem) and letting $s\to 0$? I think that trying this route is not to hard and even the Laplace transform of the fundamental solution of the heat operator seems to be not too difficult to calculate.

Answer (score 2):

I think it goes more or less as follows or at least I hope it helps,

$$
\begin{split}
u(x,t) 
 & =\lim_{t\to 0}\sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}^d}\int\limits_{[0,1]^n+z}\Phi(x-y,t)f(y)dy\\
& =\lim_{t\to 0}\sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}^d}\int\limits_{[0,1]^n+z}\Phi(y-x,t)f(y)dy\\
& =\lim_{t\to 0}\sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}^d}\int\limits_{[0,1]^n}\Phi(y+z-x,t)f(y+z)dy\\
& =\lim_{t\to 0}\sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}^d}\int\limits_{[0,1]^n}\Phi\big((z-x)+y,t\big)f(y)dy\\
& =\lim_{t\to 0}\int\limits_{[0,1]^n}f(y)\bigg(\sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}^d}\Phi\big((z-x)+y,t\big)\bigg)dy\\
& =\lim_{t\to 0}\int\limits_{[0,1]^n}f(y)\bigg(\sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}^d}\hat{\Phi}(z-x,t)e^{2\pi i zy}\bigg)dy\qquad(\text{Poisson summation formula (PSF))}\\
& =\int\limits_{[0,1]^n}\sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}^d}\Big(\lim_{t\to 0}\hat{\Phi}(z-x,t)\Big)f(y)e^{2\pi i zy}dy\\
& =\int\limits_{[0,1]^n}\sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}^d}\Big(\lim_{t\to 0}e^{-t(z-x)^2}\Big)f(y)e^{2\pi i zy}dy\\
& =\int\limits_{[0,1]^n}\sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}^d}f(y)e^{2\pi i zy}dy\\
& =\int\limits_{[0,1]^n}f(y)\bigg(\sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}^d}e^{2\pi i zy}\bigg)dy\\
& =\int\limits_{[0,1]^n}f(y)\bigg(\sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}^d}\delta(z-y)\bigg)dy\qquad\qquad\;\;\qquad(\text{PSF)}\\
&=\int\limits_{[0,1]^n}f(y)dy
\end{split}
$$

Comment: +1. Nice work. Interchanging the summation and the integration and calculating explicitly the limit is a simple but very effective idea.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri thanks, I had seen this argument before to prove a special case of the PSF $\sum f(y)=\sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}^d}\hat{f}(y)$ with $\sum f(y)=\lim_{t\to \infty}\sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}^d}\int_{[0,1]^n+z}\Phi(x-y,t)f(y)dy$ the second line and $\sum f(y)=\sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}^d}\hat{f}(y)=\int_{[0,1]^n}\sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}^d}f(y)e^{2\pi i zy}dy$ the tenth line so until there everything should be right if I reconstructed the argument correctly then what I did was nothing more than invert the sum and the integral and apply PSF again in the three last lines =)

Comment: I hope you don't mind for the edits I've done: however, if you don't like them, please feel free to revert.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Thanks, actually I'm low activity wikipedian so I appreciate collaborative work =), also I just realized I wrote t→∞ but what I had in mind and used was t→0 (edited now), I feel like at infinity time it should go to zero and that the OP really meant this case but maybe is just what I want.

Comment: 2 years later got an upvote which made me look at it again and I'm not convinced of what I did specially last step, may look at it again at another time, OP didn't accept it either so I would suggest asking if he got the answer